# Kivy ScrollView+Accordion Error

Tags: android, python, user-interface, scrollview, kivy

I have this code. If I increase the number of Accordion items past a certain amount the app goes haywire. The gridLayout version (commented out) works as expected. The offending region is between HERE and THERE.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner, SpinnerOption
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MusicController(App):

    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        top = Spinner(text = '12', values = ["Songs","Artist","Playlist","Search"], background_color = (.3,.2,.5,1), size_hint_y = 0.1)

    #< HERE >#

        items = Accordion(orientation='vertical')
        for x in xrange(30):
            item = AccordionItem(title='Title %d' % x)
            buttons = BoxLayout()
            buttons.add_widget(Button(text='Play'))
            buttons.add_widget(Button(text='Pause'))
            buttons.add_widget(Button(text='Pause'))
            item.add_widget(buttons)
            items.add_widget(item)

        #~ items = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        #~ items.bind(minimum_height=items.setter('height'))
        #~ for i in range(30):
            #~ btn = Button(text=str(i), 

    #< THERE >#

        sv = ScrollView(do_scroll_x = False)
        sv.add_widget(items)
        now_playing = BoxLayout(size_hint_y = 0.1)
        for widget in ["Prev","Play","Pause","Next","NP"]:
            now_playing.add_widget(Button(text=widget))

        b.add_widget(top)
        b.add_widget(sv)
        b.add_widget(now_playing)
        return b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MusicController().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error on you console suggests

```
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] need XXXX, got XXXXpx
[WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
```

Just increase the space given to the Accordian so it can house all it's children

changing line 19 of your code to

```
items = Accordion(orientation='vertical', size_hint_y=None, height=50*30)
```

Should work.

In GridLayout you do the same by binding the Gridlayout's `minimum_height` (which is calculated by the height of the children combined) to it's height.

```
items.bind(minimum_height=items.setter('height'))
```

Accordian has no such convenience method, so you have to do it yourself.

To make it more dynamic you could bind to the children property of the Accordion like so:

```
item.bind(children=self.update_size)
```

Then define update_size like so::

```
def update_size(self, instance, value):
    # change 50 to what you want your AccordionItem height to be.
    instance.size = 50*len(instance.children)
```

Comment: This works and I appreciate it. But why does the other container not require this and is there a way to make it more dynamic? I don't mean to sound ungrateful, I do appreciate this.

Comment: Updated the answer to include a explanation, basically you are doing the same with GridLayout by binding it's height to it's minimum_height.